# Remove extra whitespace inside textarea onclick using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I found below code to remove extra whitespace inside textarea. It works fine, but it doesn't remove extra whitespace in all row's inside textarea. I want to remove all row's extra whitespace at one single click in javascript. Please help me out of this.

Here is the code.

```
 <textarea class="input" name="input" type="text" id="txt" style="height: 250px;width: 450px;" placeholder="One Per Line"></textarea>
 <input type="button"  name="submit1" value="Clear Extra Space" id="run1"/>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#run1').click(function() {
var textarea=$('#txt'); 
textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,""));
textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," "));
textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/\n /,"\n"));
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your click event handler as, [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/khfhbc58/)

```
$('#run1').click(function() {
    var textarea=$('#txt'); 
    var rows = textarea.val().split( "\n" );
    console.log(rows);

    for ( var counter = 0; counter < rows.length; counter++)
    {
       rows[ counter ] = rows[ counter ].trim();
       if ( rows[ counter ].length == 0 )
       {
          rows.splice( counter, 1 );
          counter--;
       }
    }
    textarea.val( rows.join( "\n" ) )
});
```